# Tex4ht changes a grave accent letter ` (hex 60) to left single quotation mark (hex 0xE2 0x80 0x98)

Tags: tex4ht

I need help with this problem, as I am not able to find a fix. This is a big problem for me, since the input file contain many [grave accent characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) ` which I enter by hitting the

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when generating the HTML, they all change to Unicode Character ['LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is a big problem, since now when I copy these back, from the web page, to an application to use them, the application complain about syntax error in input.

This problem shows in both verbatim and normal latex text mode.  Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
`123`

\verb|`123`|

\end{document}
```

And how after `htlatex foo.tex`, the HTML looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But these are not what I had in the file as input. Here is the HTML source

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="foo.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2015-01-15 19:02:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo.css"> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 3--><p class="noindent" >&#8216;123&#8216;
<!--l. 5--><p class="indent" >   <span class="obeylines-h"><span class="verb"><span 
class="cmtt-12">&#8216;123&#8216;</span></span></span>

</body></html>
```

I am using texlive 2014 on linux. Updated recently. Here is the file list from the above run

```
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (./foo.aux)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./foo.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 ***********

 )</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 11730 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default behaviour, you will get the same result even with `pdflatex`. You can use `upquote` package to redefine grave and upright-quote to produce correct glyphs:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
`123`

\verb|`123`|
\end{document}
```

the result:

```xml
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >‘123‘
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >   <span class="obeylines-h"><span class="verb"><span 
class="cmtt-12">`123`</span></span></span> </p>
```