# problem using new added support for package{bera} in tex4ht

Tags: fonts, tex4ht

Now that tex4ht have added support to package `bera`, reference [how-to-use-usepackagebera-in-tex4ht-it-does-not-like-the-f-letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415418/how-to-use-usepackagebera-in-tex4ht-it-does-not-like-the-f-letter) I've been using it for little while, and just found a problem.

If `Verbatim` has something like `y''` or `y'` then in the HTML output it shows just as `y`, i.e. the primes are gone. This happens when I compiled with `--lua` option, and when I use `\usepackage{upquote}` as well.

I have been using `\usepackage{upquote}` forever, since it is needed to make tex4ht not mess up another issue, and it was recommended for me to use by @michal.h21 in this post [tex4ht-changes-a-grave-accent-letter-hex-60-to-left-single-quotation-mark-h](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223362/tex4ht-changes-a-grave-accent-letter-hex-60-to-left-single-quotation-mark-h)

So there seems to be a new conflict now between `upquote` and `bera` in `tex4ht`?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{upquote} %to handle correct tex4ht to html conversion of `
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{bera} %now tex4ht supports this, thanks to michal.h21
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
Lets try y'' and see what happens
lets try y'  and see what happens
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht --lua foo_before.tex
```

Here is the HTML output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Removing the `\usepackage{upquote}` and recompiling now the primes do show up correctly

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using texlive 2017 on Linux. here is the file list

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    bera.sty    2004/01/31 (WaS)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
beraserif.sty    2004/01/30 (WaS)
   t1fve.fd    2004/09/07 scalable font definitions for T1/fve.
berasans.sty    2004/01/30 (WaS)
beramono.sty    2004/01/31 (WaS)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
   t1fvm.fd    2004/09/07 scalable font definitions for T1/fvm.
  ts1fvm.fd    2004/09/07 scalable font definitions for TS1/fvm.
 ***********
```

This problems shows up, only when using `--lua` option. But I have to use this option.

What to do if one wants to use `bera` package in `tex4ht`, under `--lua` and also use `upquote`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that support for monospaced `bera` font is missing, so all you need is a new `htf` file, `fvmr8r.htf`:

```
.pcrro8r
htfcss: fvmr8r font-family: monospaced;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will this new file be made available in the texlive update, so that next time I update texlive, it will automatically be there? I prefer not to modify/add local files manually. If so, I will wait for next update of texlive.

Comment: I hope so, we need to wait for Karl to update TL. He is usually really fast, so it should be done in few days.